# How to make the command property of a wpf button a dependency property of a user control

Tags: wpf, vb.net, user-controls

I am trying to teach myself the basics of creating user controls in wpf.  To that end I have been experimenting with building a data navigation control to allow navigation through the records being retrieved by various view models.  My long term plan is for a completely self contained custom control, but I'd like to master the smaller points first so to that end I'd like to know how I can make the Command, and Command Parameter properties ( as well as the Is Enabled property) of buttons that form part of my user control dependency properties of the user control itself.

I have succeeded to make the various image and image height and width properties of the various buttons dependency properties of the overall user control but thus far have not had any success with the Command, Command Parameter and is Enabled properties.

I'd welcome any suggestions anyone could proffer.

I have the following already (I set for each button in my user control):

```
#Region "Next Button"
Public Property ImageNext() As ImageSource
    Get
        Return DirectCast(GetValue(ImageNextProperty), ImageSource)
    End Get
    Set(value As ImageSource)
        SetValue(ImageNextProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property


Public Shared ReadOnly ImageNextProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ImageNext", GetType(ImageSource), GetType(DataNavigator), New UIPropertyMetadata(Nothing))

Public Property ImageNextWidth() As Double
    Get
        Return CDbl(GetValue(ImageNextWidthProperty))
    End Get
    Set(value As Double)
        SetValue(ImageNextWidthProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property


Public Shared ReadOnly ImageNextWidthProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ImageNextWidth", GetType(Double), GetType(DataNavigator), New UIPropertyMetadata(16.0))

Public Property ImageNextHeight() As Double
    Get
        Return CDbl(GetValue(ImageNextHeightProperty))
    End Get
    Set(value As Double)
        SetValue(ImageNextHeightProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property


    Public Shared ReadOnly ImageNextHeightProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ImageNextHeight", GetType(Double), GetType(DataNavigator), New UIPropertyMetadata(16.0))
```

This however has been adding properties to standard wpf buttons, now what I want to do is access properties of those buttons that already exist and bind to them (via my user control)  from my viewmodels

Answer (score 0):

It is the same as any other dependency property. 
You declare the DP like this:

```
Public Shared ReadOnly ThisCommandProperty As DependencyProperty = _
    DependencyProperty.Register("ThisCommand", GetType(ICommand), _
           GetType(thiscontrol), Nothing)

Public Property ThisCommand As ICommand
    Get
        Return CType(GetValue(ThisCommandProperty), ICommand)
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As ICommand)
        SetValue(ThisCommandProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property
```

and in the XAML of your user control:

```xml
<UserControl ...> 
    <Button Command={Binding ThisCommand} ... />
</UserControl>
```

You set the parameter in the same way, but with type `object`, and you have to cast it so the correct type in your command handler.

When you use the `UserControl`, it is like this:

```xml
<local:thisControl ThisCommand={Binding whateverCommandYouWantToBindTo}, 
    ThisCommandParameter={Binding whateverParameterYouWant)>
```

It is really just the same as any other DP, except for the type. Of course, `whateverCommandYouWantToBindTo` has to be set up as an ICommand too.

People might also [tell you that defining usercontrols is bad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2313320/5336967) and to use templates instead, and it's probably a better approach in most cases. But if you want to learn about DPs, I say learn.

Here is an example that I have working in front of me:

```
Public Shared ReadOnly EditButtonCommandProperty As DependencyProperty = _
    DependencyProperty.Register("EditButtonCommand", _
          GetType(ICommand), GetType(PersonListControl), Nothing)

Public Property EditButtonCommand As ICommand
    Get
        Return CType(GetValue(EditButtonCommandProperty), ICommand)
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As ICommand)
        SetValue(EditButtonCommandProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property

Public Shared ReadOnly EditButtonCommandParameterProperty As DependencyProperty = _
    DependencyProperty.Register("EditButtonCommandParameter", GetType(Object), _
            GetType(PersonListControl), Nothing);

Public Property EditButtonCommandParameter As Object
    Get
        Return CType(GetValue(EditButtonCommandParameterProperty), Object)
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Object)
        SetValue(EditButtonCommandParameterProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property
```

And in the UserControl XAML:

```xml
<StackPanel>
    <ListBox ... />
    <Button 
        ...
        Command="{Binding EditButtonCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding EditButtonCommandParameter}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

And I use this UserControl like this:

```xml
<local:PersonListControl
    ...
    EditButtonCommand="{Binding PersonListEditCommand}"
    EditButtonCommandParameter="{Binding Parents}"/>
```

Comment: Nathan, that was a _lot of editing! Tranlation to VB _and correction of my grammar. Thank you very much :-)

Comment: I see the same question has also be answered over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777452/wpf-usercontrols-setting-the-command-property-on-button-inside-usercontrol?rq=1